# display validation messages using JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

How can I return custom validation messages using JsonResult and AJAX?

Here is my controller action to add a student in StudentDB.

**UPDATED:**

```
    [HttpPost()]
    public ActionResult AddStudent(string studentName, int studentId)
    {
        var studentPresent = studentTable.Students.Where(s => s.StudentID == studentId&& b.StudentName == studentName);

        if (studentPresent == null || !studentPresent .Any())
        {
            var student = new Student()
                {
                    StudentName = studnetName,
                    StudentID = studentId,
                };
            studentTable.AddObject("Student", student);
            studentTable.SaveChanges();

         }
        return new JsonResult();      

    }
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function addStudent() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/StudentAdmin/AddStudent',
        data: {
            studentName: $('#studentName').val(),
            studentNumber: GetTextBoxValue('#studentNumber'),            
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if ($('#studentPresent').val() == null) {
            showMessage('Success', 'Student saved successfully.', '', false);                
        } else {
            showMessage('Error', 'Student already present in database.', '', false);
        }
            GetGrid('#studentGrid').ajaxRequest();
            hideForm();
        },
        studentPresent: function (result) {
            showMessage('Error', 'Student Already present in Database.', '', true);
        }

    });
}
```

I want to display the "error" message if this student is already present in database.
Also, Is there a way of passing more validation messages to JasonResult?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hope this will help http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.com/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-using-jsonresult.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any object to the `JsonResult` object and it will be serialized (or it will attempt to serialize) down to the javascript.

```
return new JsonResult(new { Anything = "Hello World" });
```

That results in a JSON object like so:

```
{"Anything":"Hello World"}
```

Being rendered to your javascript in the `result` variable.

Your code above actually doesn't show any error message being generated; you would need a try / catch block if you want to get the text of the SQL exception.

EDIT:

You would have code like so:

```
return Json(new { message = "Success" }); // success message
return Json(new { message = "Failure" }); // fail message
```

And then in javascript, your callback is like so:

```
success: function(result)
{
     if(result.message == "Success")
       // Show success message
     else
       // Show Error Message
}
```

Comment: Get an error: System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument when I try the following:                  return new JsonResult(new { result = "Success" });

Comment: You should be able to use the helper method: `return Json(someObject)`; I was confused. You simply set the `Data` property on the JsonResult, not in the constructor.

Comment: If I pass an object like this:return new Json(new { result = "Success" }); 
 it still gives me an error: System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json is a method but is used like a type

Comment: remove the `new Json` and replace with `Json` - it's a method.

Comment: Yes, I did that. No errors now. However, it wont display the error message. It always displays the Success message, even if the condition is not met.

Comment: You're going to have to post updated code for me to properly help you.

Comment: Updated controller action above.

Comment: The `error` callback is only invoked when the HTTP request does not come back as HTTP 200. The text is being returned in your `success` callback, so you need to inspect the values there.

Comment: ok, so even after changing the result to something different like "studentPresent" wont trigger other message. My aim here is to show a message "Student is already present in database" when someone tries to add an already existing student in database. Would I need to approach this differently?

Comment: Can we accomplish what I want by doing it this way?

Comment: You would need to inspect the result you received in your success callback and then act appropriately.

Comment: I tried displaying different messages based on the value of "studentPresent" variable. But, I am still not able to get this to work. Even if the student is present in DB, it still shows the "Success" message. However the student doesn't get added again. I have udpated my code above.

Comment: Updated with a code sample. You may need to convert the JSON into an object, so luckily jQuery has a `$.parseJSON` function.

Comment: thanks! that worked. However, why wouldnt passing the "studentVariable" value not work but passing the message would?

Answer (score 1):

You can `return Json(new {result = "Success"});`

Comment: I get the following error on 'Json':System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json is a method but is used like a type

Comment: I have edited it. Just remove the new before Json. Please check it again.